# Using IP authenticated proxies in a distributed crawler

Tags: python, proxy, web-crawler

I'm working on a distributed web crawler in Python running on a cluster of CentOS 6.3 servers, the crawler uses many proxies from different proxy providers. Everything works like a charm for username/password authenticated proxy providers. But now we have bought some proxies that uses IP based authentication, this means that when I want do crawl into a webpage using one of this proxies I need to make the request from a subset of our servers.

The question is, is there a way in Python (using a library/software) to make a request to a domain passing trough 2 proxies? (one proxy is one of the subset needed to be used for the IP authentication and the second is the actual proxy from the provider) Or is there another way to do this without setting up this subset of our servers as proxies?

The code I'm using now to make the request trough a proxy uses the requests library:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

proxy_obj = {
    'http':proxy['ip']
}

auth = HTTPProxyAuth(proxy['username'], proxy['password')

data = requests.get(url, proxies = proxy_obj, auth = auth)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use proxies at all? Can't your cluster just hit the remote hosts directly?

Comment: Okay. Should be possible using Python. What code do you have so far for your proxy-based access? Are you using `httplib` or `sockets` or something else?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to add a sample of the code I'm using now, it uses the requests library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way in Python (using a library/software) to make a request
>   to a domain passing trough 2 proxies?

If you need to go through two proxies, it looks like you'll have to use [HTTP tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel), so any host which isn't on the authorized list would have to connect an HTTP proxy server on one of the hosts which is, and use the HTTP `CONNECT` method to create a tunnel to the remote proxy, but it may not be possible to achieve that with the `requests` library.

> Or is there another way to do this without setting up this subset of
>   our servers as proxies?

Assuming that the remote proxies which use IP address-based authentication are all expecting the same IP address, then you could instead configure a NAT router, between your cluster and the remote proxies, to translate all outbound HTTP requests to come from that single IP address.

But, before you look into implementing either of these unnecessarily complicated options, and given that you're paying for this service, can't you just ask the provider to allow requests for the entire range of IP addresses which you're currently using?